# SourceTree on Windows: How to connect to SSH?

Tags: windows, git, ssh, putty, atlassian-sourcetree

I have an SSH access to my web hosting, it works great with PuTTY (I just had to enter my domain, username and password), however it seems much more complicated with SourceTree.

While PuTTY has a field for "Host Name", "username" and "password", SourceTree doesn't and requires a special file "`.ppk`"?!

I need to connect SourceTree to my web hosting via SSH for the obvious reason that I want to use it to push to a remote repository located on my web hosting.

So **how do I get a `.ppk` file generated from my domain/username/password?** Any help greatly appreciated!

*PS: I've noticed that they made it exceptionally easy to connect to BitBucket by offering two simple fields: "username" and "password", and made it exceptionally difficult to connect to a third-party SSH... Is it an intentional attempt to prevent competition?!*

Answer (score 26, accepted):

There are two ways to connect SourceTree to any SSH.

### 1: The Simplest Way

**The simplest way is by using your domain name, username and password provided by your Web Hosting Provider:**

Simply use the following syntax: `ssh://username@example.com/` – SourceTree will then prompt you to enter your password whenever you push to that SSH:

[image: SourceTree SSH Password Prompt]

If you check the `Remember password` checkbox, your password will be saved and you will not be prompted again for it. You can edit or remove the stored password at a later time by going to `Tools > Options > Authentication` as shown on the image below:

[image: SourceTree Windows Authentication Panel]

Note: In my case (1&1 Shared Hosting), the username and password were both the same as my main FTP account.

## 2: The More Complex Way

**The more complex way is by using a Private/Public Keys Pair:**

This implies generating two keys (one "private" and one "public") using the "*PuTTY Key Generator*" (in SourceTree go to `Tools > Create or Import SSH Keys`).

Once generated, save the private key to a `.ppk` file and load it in SourceTree (`Tools > Create or Import SSH Keys > Load`). It's not over yet: now you must add the public key to your server. To do that, add it to the following file on your web server: `/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

If this file doesn't exist, save your public key to a file named `authorized_keys` and upload it to your server via FTP. You must upload it into a directory named `/.ssh/` located at the root (if it doesn't exist, simply create it).

Note: Make sure to use the *main* FTP account of your hosting account. If it doesn't work, adjust the permissions (chmod) of the `authorized_keys` file and set it to `777` using your FTP software (`Right-click on "authorized_keys" > File permissions`):

[image: FileZilla FTP Client Change File Permissions]

[image: FileZilla FTP Client on Windows - Set chmod]

No need for command line whatsoever.

Comment: Where do I enter this?? ssh://username@example.com/

Comment: @OZZIE under `Repository` > `Repository Settings` > `Add` > `URL/Path`

Comment: Is it possible to connect using an rsa-key somehow? I'm not allowed to add new keys

Comment: @Community Is this an answer for this question too? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38291364/controlling-git-repository-remotely

Comment: After much hair-pulling I discovered that the simple way (which is really the most convenient way for most users) only works if you have chosen plink first. If you happen to have chosen OpenSSH (which was the first thing I did) then you never get prompted for your password.

Answer (score 32):

I had to do some additional work from [Patoshi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39498801/352349).

In Tools > Options > General > SSH Client Configuration, I had to point it to the id_rsa key, and select OpenSSH as the SSH Client (Putty/PLink is selected by default).
[image: SSH Client Configuration]

Then each time you start SourceTree, a prompt will appear asking for the passphrase to decrypt the id_rsa key (assuming you created it with a passphrase to encrypt it). This looks like so:
[image: passphrase prompt]

At that point, I could go to the Clone page, paste in the SSH address from my Gitlab project (git@localgit.local:Blah/Whatever.git) and it cloned it. No extra prompts for username or password (since it is using SSH keys).

Comment: Another answer made me realize I had to use OpenSSH instead of Putty when exporting (I already had openssh key so didn't need to export) and importing. Your answer does too but it wasn't in *bold* so I didn't realize it.

Comment: Worked, default Putty option was the reason for not importing or finding my id_rsa file. Thanks

Answer (score 9):

I had some trouble getting SourceTree working with an existing git repo that resided on gitlab. I also had to figure out why it wasn't connecting as I was using puttygen to generate the keys.

**Make sure after you generate your keys to export it to the OpenSSH format**

[image]

You place this file in your c:\user\MYUSERNAME.ssh folder as the file:

- id_rsa
- id_rsa.pub

the id_rsa is the private key file and .pub is the public key file that you paste into your other application, which in my case was gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate SSH key, private and public

- Source Tree > Tools > Create or Import SSH Keys

2. Putty

- Click Generate
- Save public key under .ssh folder
- Save private key under .ssh folder

3. Add private key to Pageant, running in background
4. Clone the git project using SSH key

Answer (score 0):

In "SSH Client Configuration" section under Tools -> Options -> General, select SSH Client as Putty. If you select as OpenSSH, you will end up with "Error: Unable to negotiate with xx.xx.xx.xx port xx: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).