# Maven JGitFlow plugin authentication for HTTPS

Tags: git, maven, authentication, bitbucket

I'm having trouble authenticating with BitBucket through HTTPS via the `Maven JGitFlow` plugin, run through `git-bash` on Windows.

The error message is: *"Authentication is required but no CredentialsProvider has been registered"*. The suggestions I've seen though seem to assume that I have access to the JGit code itself as a developer.

I've had no trouble executing git commands **directly** (I'm using `git-credential-winstore`). Also, when I've supplied my username and password in the POM explicitly in the pom.xml file, it also worked.

However, I would not like my password to be uploaded to my BitBucket repository, and am looking for a way for the `JGitFlow` plugin to authenticate the same way as GIT itself does.

What am I doing wrong, and how can I fix that?

Comment: Have you considered to switch from the HTTPS to SSH authentication? There is a simple instruction how to do it: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-an-ssh-key-728138079.html#SetupanSSHkey-ssh1

Comment: And some links for those who use SourceTree on how to switch it to SSH authentication based on OpenSSH (which is the default for Git on Windows): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/use-ssh-keys-to-authenticate?view=vsts#how-can-i-start-using-ssh-in-a-repository-where-i-am-currently-using-https https://stackoverflow.com/a/47930338/355438

Comment: I recently found a project on github which supersedes on the idea (Not sure if it is a straight continuation), but it works with https authentication: https://github.com/aleksandr-m/gitflow-maven-plugin

Answer (score 9):

The following JGitFlow Maven plugin configuration works

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>external.atlassian.jgitflow</groupId>
    <artifactId>jgitflow-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-m5.1</version>
    <configuration>
        <username>${git.user}</username>
        <password>${git.password}</password>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Call it from the command line with the username and password as Java System Properties, i.e. with `-Dgit.user=<user>` and `-Dgit.password=<password>`, e.g.

> mvn -Dgit.user=user@bitbucket.com -Dgit.password=secret jgitflow:release-start

Note: the plugin should really be updated with a Maven `CredentialsProvider` that is capable of obtaining the credentials from `settings.xml` and/or a Git credentials parser that uses the same mechanism as git on the command line.

Comment: This is a clever solution I did not think about. However, would that make everyone who wants to work on my project have to do it as well (even if they use another form of credentials)?

Comment: Yes, each time they use the release plugin they would need to provide credentials. It _may_ be that they are only needed when you connect to the remote repository, I have not tested. Our use case is bungled as we also need to pass the credentials to a proxy...

Comment: While that improves the situation (my credentials will not be shared with the people I collaborate with), that still forces my way of doing things (so it seems not well suited for public repositories, for example).